# Python Django does not see the CSS file

Tags: python, django

I **just started** using **Django**, which I initially had a lot of problems with, but that's not the point. I launched a **new project** about 4 times, it turned out that through the console it did not create a complete list of folders and files and I had to create them **manually**. I created and added an init file everywhere so that Python sees this folder, however, when I need to **insert a Banner photo** for my profile, when I start the server through the console and the python **manage.py runserver command**, although it launches my entire HTML structure, **it does not display the photo** , which I inserted there initially.

I tried to change the location of the folders, I tried to change the location of the photos and it didn’t bring much results. Also, I changed settings.py and urls several times, but this also did not change anything, perhaps I made a mistake in the code or missed something?

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css' %}" />
  <title>Your Profile</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo"><span class="tf-logo">{{ title }}</span></div>

  <button class="sidebar-button">
    <img src="{% static 'photo/home1.png' %}" alt="Home">
    <span>
      Home
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="sidebar-button">
    <img src="{% static 'css/search2.png' %}" alt="Search">
    <span>
      Search
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="sidebar-button">
    <img src="{% static 'css/envelope3.png' %}" alt="Messages">
    <span>
      Messages
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="sidebar-button">
    <img src="{% static 'css/heart1.png' %}" alt="Favorites">
    <span>
      Favorites
    </span>
  </button>
 </div>

    <div class="flexcontainer">
        <div class="profile-container">
            <div class="middle">
                <section class="SecondaryNick">
                    <div class="TopUsername">
                        <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>
                        <span>
                        {% if user.sketches.count > 0 %}
                            {{ user.sketches.counts }} <h1>Sketches</h1>
                        {% else %}
                            <h1>No Sketches Yet</h1>
                        {% endif %}
                        </span>
                    </div>>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section class="profile">
            <div class="dlinayakartinka">
                 <img src="{% static 'banner.jpg' %}" height="300" width="933" alt="banner" id="banner"/>
            </div>>
        </section>
    </div>>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe I'm wrong and I need to add a variable there at the {{ user.banner }} level, as stated above, but I'm not sure if this will help.  This is a piece of code that may cause problems.
​

```
<div class="dlinayakartinka">
                     <img src="{% static 'banner.png' %}" height="300" width="933" alt="banner" id="banner"/>
                </div>>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.profile, name='profile'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'E:/DjangoProject/TF/TF/static'
```

​
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def profile(request):
    context = {'title': 'Profile Page'}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-8t2ir6yr$swal3zr=hrly9+%j06uwlwp8-i_p18glf8uah(ecj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TF.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['E:/DjangoProject/TF/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TF.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'E:/DjangoProject/TF/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

here are screenshots of the server, file paths, and so on.

[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wZ8E.png)

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aG8o.png)

[also path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r94Ri.png)

Comment: What is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css' %}" />` supposed to do? `css` is not the CSS file.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem

In WebStorm, this parameter was enough for the IDE to completely look at all the folders inside it; it seemed to me that by dividing the folders into their categories and specifying exclusively the CSS folder as the main one, where all the files are located, that would be enough, isn’t it? And, for example, if you change this data to the name of the profile.css files, nothing has changed, again, maybe I don’t fully understand something.

Comment: No, lucky enough that is not sufficient, since that would imply there is an immense security hole that the webserver somehow returns the filetree. The IDE might perhaps be willing to repalce it with a sequence of CSS calls, but it would be security-wise a terrible idea that you can pass a wildcard to the browser to load all css in a directory.

Comment: In that case, do I need to specify each folder separately or what? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Remove STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL assignments from urls.py, put them to settings.py and fix `STATIC_URL = 'E:/DjangoProject/TF/static/'` - this value is supposed to be `STATIC_ROOT`, not `_URL` and it does not match what you specified in urls.py

Comment: `each folder separately or what?` each css file

Comment: Thank you very much, I’ll be sure to write down a little later how everything went, most likely this will be the solution.

Comment: It seems to have worked, at least for now. Thank you)